# spring security allow an user to reset only their password

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

i've a controller that allow to  update user info

```
@RequestMapping(value = "user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody User user) {
```

In this way only user that have the role ADMIN to update an user. I want to modify the secutiry in this way:

- an user without role admin can update only him info
- an admin can update every user

There is a way to implement this using spring secutiry tag ?

Thanks
Esoni

Comment: `@PreAuthorize('hasRole('ADMIN') or #user.name == authority.name)` something along those lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do Something like this

```
  @PreAuthorize("#user.username==principal.username || hasRole('ADMIN')")
```

This checks whether logged in users username name and the username for update are same or user has a role admin.